# Getting shaded boxes in lists to indent

Tags: lists, indentation, framed

I'm trying to make a list which also contains theorems in shaded boxes. I'm currently using the framed package to do this. However, the shaded boxes do not properly "tab" inward to align with the list's item. Instead, the left side of the shaded box extends all the way to the margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed, amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{AliceBlue}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{thm}{\begin{shaded*}\begin{theo}}{\end{theo}\end{shaded*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
        \begin{thm} Theorem in shaded box. \end{thm} 
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The shaded box surrounding the theorem is not indented, but rather extends all the way to the left margin. Is there any way to get around this, or another package you'd recommend to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you provide a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that includes definitions for `AliceBlue` and `theo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shaded*` and friends always put their edge at margins. From documentation:

[image]

Hence as a work around, you can use an additional `minipage`

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{framed,xcolor,amsthm}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{olive}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thm}{%
    \par
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{shaded*}
    \begin{theo}}%
    {\end{theo}
    \end{shaded*}
    \end{minipage}%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
        \begin{thm} Theorem in shaded box. \end{thm}
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternate option would be to use powerful `tcolorbox` to put the background.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thm}{%   
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,colback=olive,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt]
    \begin{theo}}%
    {\end{theo}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
        \begin{thm} Theorem in shaded box. \end{thm}
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]